# Replace For and If to make code faster

Tags: vba, for-loop, slowdown

I'm new with VBA and I wrote multible little makros to compare to sheets for changes. One sheet has 40000 rows and I used For and If conditions. is it possible to replace them, to make the makro work faster. now my makro ist workin for 100 rows but for more excel does not respond.

It would be glad if someone coul help me, I dont know what to do.

```
Sub OldT() 'Time

Worksheets("Old").Activate

For zOld = 2 To 100
    For zNew = 2 To 100
        If Worksheets("Old").Cells(zOld, 5) = Worksheets("New").Cells(zNew, 5) And Worksheets("Old").Cells(zOld, 12) = Worksheets("New").Cells(zNew, 12) Then
            Worksheets("Old").Cells(zOld, 18) = Worksheets("New").Cells(zNew, 8)
        Exit For
        End If
    Next zNew
Next zOld
End Sub
```

Comment: Start by putting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end.

Comment: Hello, thanks but i already have them in the Main Sub Call Makro, here i just wanted to show one small Makro. I have about 8 small Makros like the one above with "For".

Comment: For example i have also a litte Makro like this, which is too slow.                                                                                                      `Sub Time()

For zStatus = 2 To 40000


Worksheets("New").Activate

If Sheets("New").Cells(zDurum, 19) > 0 Then
Cells(zDurum, 20).Value = "greater"


ElseIf Sheets("New").Cells(zStatus, 19) < 0 Then
Cells(zStatus, 20).Value = "smaller"


ElseIf Sheets("New").Cells(zStatus, 19) = 0 Then
Cells(zStatus, 20).Value = "same"

End If
    Next zStatus
End Sub`

Comment: Please don't put code in comments, this is nearly unreadable. Anyhow, I think for this example you should use a formula rather than VBA code.
`=IF(S3>0,"larger";IF(S3<0,"Smaller", "Equal"))`